# Bluescreen at win7 Boot (Boot time defrag routine failure)

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod, defragment

I had this drive set up for boot time defrag (only once). It contained a pagefile which was fragmented.

Next time I restarted my PC, I got a bluescreen (dumping memory). 
After a few repair attempts, windows finally gave up.

The error that I got said something about "error in non-paged memory"

I ran CPU diagnostics and RAM diagnostics from my other OS, as well as win7 bootmgr. There's no hardware failure. Once, it even got to the boot-time defrag routine screen before showing the bluescreen.

I'm inclined to think that the defrag program is attempting to defragment the pagefile even though it's supposed to be locked by the OS, after the bootscreen. (perhaps the boot-time defrag routine isn't that smart)

So is there a way to remove that defrag routine from windows startup so that I may be able to get into the OS and do the necessary changes to keep this from happening again?

Or is there a way to remove it from the program settings itself (of course by using the file system from another OS), to keep it from trying to defrag that drive? I use O&O Defrag 17.

Comment: call the O&O support on how to remove the boot defragmentation of their tool.

Comment: Boot from a live cd (os of your choice) and delete the pagefile.sys file from the root of the drive.